# Insert Dates with a value in UITableView Obj C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, date

I have a variable startDate and also another monthsRem

monthsRem contains a value of months, e.g. 24

I need to populate the UITableView with a list of dates up until the values of months from the start date providing other sources of data.

e.g:

date 5th april 2011, monthsRem 12

so it would show:

5th May - value

5th June - value

etc...

Can anyone guide me on what I need to do to get this concept going, my main struggle is with the UITableView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question's title implies that you are thinking about this backwards.  In UIKit (and Cocoa), you don't insert values into a Table View, you provide a data source and the table view asks said data source for values, as needed.

If you look at the top of just about an class reference in the UIKit (or Cocoa) documentation, you'll generally find a programming guide or set of programming guides that go into great detail on how to effectively use the class in your app.

[UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a link to the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451), for example.  There are also a ton of sample code/projects at the top of the class reference.